# Cannot activate venv & there is no 'Scripts' Folder

Tags: python, django, cmd, virtualenv

I'm trying to make a **venv**, but the activation step, is not working and raises error below:

`'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

First of all I'm using windows-OS, but the files that made by the command: `python -m venv env_name` are: [click here to see the files pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80P1H.jpg). and instead of 'Scripts' Folder it made 'bin' Folder.
Anyway, I've tried this code: `env_name/bin/activate`. But instead of making the env, it raised the error that i mentioned before.

i will be appreciated if someone help. thanks

Comment: How did you create that virtual environment?

Comment: made a file and changed the directory to it, and using "python -m venv env_name" made the env

Comment: Are you using WSL or mingw64?  What is the python executable of the virtual environment? You can check it by checking the `home` inside the `pyvenv.cfg` inside the virtual environment folder.

Comment: looks like your folder created was named "myenv" therefore you activate it by myenv/scripts/activate

Comment: @NikoFohr
 I'm using mingw64

Comment: @Aristotle There is no 'Scripts' Folder.

Comment: you'll need myenv/bin/activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
In my case, I tried using Windows-PowerShell, and by default, the **execution policy**, was set to **Restricted**, and with [this solution](https://tecadmin.net/powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-system/#:%7E:text=To%20resolve%20the%20%E2%80%9CRunning%20scripts,select%20%E2%80%9CRun%20as%20administrator%E2%80%9D.), I've changed it to **RemoteSigned** and all done.